# Show text label next to the input box?

Tags: css

How can I show the label 'RegularExpressionValidator' on the right to the input
box and align the input box?

Putting it outside the div makes the label to the left on the other side.
[image]

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
<!--
label{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
}
-->
</style>
...........

<div style="text-align:center;">
        <label>Phone:</label>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="req_Phone" ControlToValidate="formWphone">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:textbox id="formWphone" runat="server" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="formWphone" 
            ValidationExpression= "">Enter valid Phone number</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you've center-aligned all of the content in the wrapper div:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
```

When extra text is added, it changes the width of the content to be centered.

Try changing this to:

```
<div style="text-align:left;">
```

or remove the style altogether.

Then if you need some space on the left, add some padding or margin to the container div.

Comment: how about if i wanted to center it? sorry for not showing all the code, its too much